# Почему вылетает Permission denied при запуске программы...

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте! Почему при запуске программы появляется  Permission denied?
Вот код этой программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{int i, pid, status, w;
for (i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
pid = fork();
if (pid ==0)
exit(getpid() % 256);
}
while ((w = wait(&status))&& w!= -1)
printf ("Child %x status %x\n", w, status);
return 0;
}
```

Как запустить эту программу???? Я вроде как имею права root.

Comment: sudo must help

Comment: Покажите результаты выполнения команды ls -l

Comment: Спасибо за внимание,всё начало работать после подключения <signal.h>

Comment: Вообще-то, в приведенный текст нужно  еще включить sys/wait.h и stdlib.h

Answer (score 5):

Странно это, [[@Alerr](/users/3147/alerr)](/users/3147/alerr).  Как Вы сумели добиться такого поведения программ? Поделитесь опытом.

Вот я взял Ваш текст и получилось следующее:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Child 753 status 5300
Child 754 status 5400
Child 755 status 5500
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Да, компилятор выдает warning, но все запускается и работает. Даже если **выбросить все  #include** из Вашей программы ситуация принципиально не меняется.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
t.c:12: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Child 650 status 5000
Child 651 status 5100
Child 652 status 5200
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Предполагая, что Вы весьма педантичны, я вызвал `gcc -Wall -Werror t.c`,  но и в этом случае добился лишь

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

и то, лишь предварительно удалив ./a.out

Поделитесь, что Вы делали, чтобы добиться `permission denied`.

Comment: Есть предположение, что у меня какой-то левый Linux.... и только.
Скачивал давно, не помню откуда...

Comment: Что значит - левый? Возраст тоже не должен иметь значение.